# Select working days from a calendar in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a calendar which look like this in SQL Server

```
Date        WorkingDay
20200514    1
20200515    1
20200516    0
20200517    0
20200518    1
20200519    1
20200520    1
20200521    0
20200522    1
```

I am trying to select the third working day from a specific date. 
If I start the 20200514, result must be the 20200518.
I try with a query like this but I do not have the date, only a list of result

```
select top 3 *
from tmp_workingdays
where workingday = 1 and date >= 20200514
order by date asc
```

How can I select only the date?

Comment: It is a caldendar update by user. Not only weekend are exclude. It is a closing schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/359a7/2).

```
select
    date
from
(
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over (order by date) as rnk
    from tmp_workingdays 
    where workingday=1 
    and date >= 20200514
) val
where rnk = 3
```

output:

```
|  Date    |  
------------
|2020-05-18|
```

Comment: I like the way you do this, but I have an error with the where rnk = 3 in SQL server. I can't find the reason why !

Comment: @Etienne I have updated my answer, try now. Also I have provided a demo.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @date AS DATE = '2020-05-14' ;
WITH cte_WorkingDates AS
(
    SELECT  [Date]
    FROM    tmp_workingdays
    WHERE   WorkingDay = 1
)
SELECT      [Date]
FROM        cte_WorkingDates
WHERE       [Date] >= @date
ORDER BY    [Date] ASC
OFFSET      2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select date 
from tmp_workingdays 
where workingday = 1 
  and date >= 20200514
order by date asc
OFFSET 2 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although your answer is good, it would be helpful for the  user to add a few commentary lines.

Comment: @Etienne . . . This is actually the best approach.